# wpa_cli store hash password

Tags: wpa-supplicant, wpa-cli

Using wpa_passphrase I can get a config with the password stored as a hash but when saving a new network with wpa_cli it gets saved as plain text. Is there a way to save passwords as a hash from wpa_cli or would I actually need to manually change it each time?